# Apache Spark Driver, Application and Calculate resources

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to Apache Spark. I would like to ask some questions related to Apache Spark.

1. What is driver in Apache Spark?
2. What is application in Apache Spark?
3. Why do we need driver and application in Apache Spark? When is application running in Apache Spark Master (localhost:8080)? When is driver running in Spark Master (localhost:8080)?
4. How to calculate resource for Apache Spark application (Worker, CPU, MEMORY..) in standalone cluster mode?

Thank in advances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Driver is your main jvm where your code executes and your Spark UI is based at. It is scheduling distributed jobs on Executors and coordinates it all, collects/prints results
2. When you start Spark app - it is an Application.
3. Driver is basically your app when you started SparkSession/SparkContext. It is running on localhost:8080 if you deployment mode is local.
4. Please match your resources to data that you consume/process. 1 kafka partition = 1 spark partition (1 core). Executors*Cores = your execution thread pool. App submits tasks to that pool. Table with 200 files = 200+ tasks. Each file/partition should be of 128mb-256mb size, if less - there is overhead if total tasks per job > your total cores.

Use formula 1 core = 5gb memory when you have real data.

Comment: Can we use rest api instead of spark sumit? I am really confused. Can you clarify?

Comment: @S.Mom You can use rest api of your Cluster Manager, e.g. Yarn/SparkStandalone Cluster, but it is very complicated.